# Data from parse is not being passed through prepareForSegue

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I want to get the objectId from parse and pass it through segue. But the objectId is passing over as an empty string:

```
class QueryViewController: UIViewController {

var objectIdFormParse = String()

@IBAction func makeQueryButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

makeSearchObject.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
        if error == nil {
            if let getObjectId = makeSearchObject.objectId {
             self.objectIdFormParse = getObjectId
                print("objectId in queryVC: \(self.objectIdForomParse)")
            }
            //Successfully saved
        } else {
            //Error, check error
        }
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: resultsSegue, sender: self)
}

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == resultsSegue
        {
            let destination = segue.destination as! ResultsViewController

            destination.objectIdFromQueryVC = objectIdForomParse
        }
    }
}
```

The print statement prints the objectId correctly, but the segue passes empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the data through perform segue. just change perform segue line with following one:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: resultsSegue, sender: objectIdForomParse)
```

And in your prepare for segue method add following lines:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == resultsSegue
        {
            let destination = segue.destination as! ResultsViewController
            let objectIDParse = sender as! String
            destination.objectIdFromQueryVC = objectIDParse
        }
    }
}
```

Perform segue when your error is nil since you are setting objectIdForomParse
only when your error is nil.

Update :

```
@IBAction func makeQueryButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

makeSearchObject.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
        if error == nil {
            if let getObjectId = makeSearchObject.objectId {
             self.objectIdFormParse = getObjectId
                print("objectId in queryVC: \(self.objectIdForomParse)")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: resultsSegue, sender: self)
            }
            //Successfully saved
        } else {
            //Error, check error
        }
    }

}

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == resultsSegue
        {
            let destination = segue.destination as! ResultsViewController

            destination.objectIdFromQueryVC = objectIdForomParse
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Off course should the segue be performed when error is nil.. Thanks